# Return an array list from java servlet to C#

Tags: c#, java, servlets

After much struggling, i have come to a design dead end :( seeing as i am a student, and all my bosses have buggered of for christams i have no one to ask!

I have managed to make my servlet process the required information, based on a parameter passed in and put it all in to a arraylist of my own class design.

for example class a has 7 strings and 1 array, and i have an arraylist of

The issue is, now i need to return this information to c#, c# is going to have no idea about class a, as well as probably having different implementation/understanding of an array list :(

What can i do to get the data in a format the is exchangable?

Thanks for the help

Comment: how do you communicate between C# and Java? And, instead of writing confusing statements such as "for example class a has 7 strings and 1 array, and i have an arraylist of", just add sample code. Will be much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to encode them as name/value parameter strings and encode them in the HTTP response.  Let the HTTP client, be it written in C# or any other language, fetch the values out of the response stream.

Another choice would be to serialize the objects as XML and send that back.  Or perhaps JSON will work.

But you are correct - clients will only know HTTP, not Java or C# classes.

Answer (score 0):

Communicate through files, sockets, or web services.